# Как найти значение между двух цветов?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

У меня есть два цвета например `color_1=QtGui.QColor('#0000ff')` и `color_2=QtGui.QColor('#ff0000')`

Я хочу водить значение переменной `val`и получать среднее между двумя цветами

например

если `val=10` то `color = '#0000ff'`

если `val=0` то `color = '#ff0000'`

если `val=3`то `color = color_1.30%+color_2.70%`

если `val=5`то `color = color_1.50%+color_2.50%`

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c1 = '#0000ff'
c2 = '#ff0000'

c1b = bytes.fromhex(c1[1:])
c2b = bytes.fromhex(c2[1:])

color3 = bytes(map( lambda chan: int(chan[0]*0.3 + chan[1]*0.7), zip(c1b, c2b)))

print("#"+ color3.hex())
```

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html

Если просто среднее то перевод в модель `RGB` и среднее значение каналов.

Если делать тарнзишн то в модель `HSL`

- `Hue` тон (нужно считать подобно `delta angle` поскольку это зацикленный круг)
- `Saturation` насыщенность
- `Light` яркость

Answer (score 0):

не уверен что понимаю вас, так как вы не указали какие цвета вы ожидаете получить.

Глядя на ваши формулы предлагаю попробовать так:

```
c1 = '#0000ff'
c2 = '#ff0000'
 
color1 = f"#{hex(int(c1[1:], 16))[2:]:>06}"
color2 = f"#{hex(int(c2[1:], 16))[2:]:>06}"
color3 = f"#{hex(int(c1[1:], 16)//3 + int(c2[1:], 16)//7)[2:]:>06}"
color4 = f"#{hex(int(c1[1:], 16)//5 + int(c2[1:], 16)//5)[2:]:>06}"
 
print(f'{color1}\n{color2}\n{color3}\n{color4}')
```

Результат:

```
#0000ff
#ff0000
#246e0b
#330033
```

Comment: поканально надо смешивать) нельзя просто так поделить цвет

Comment: Как это у вас при 50% смешивании `#330033` получилось?